# How to output every `log` as `ln` in tex output in maxima?

Tags: maxima

So I tried

`texput(%e, "\e"); texput(log, "\\ln");`

But if I call the `tex` function:

`tex(%e*log(3));`

This gives:

`$$\e\,\log 3$$`

But I actually expected:

`$$\e\,\ln 3$$`

So my question is how to output every `log` as `ln` in tex output in maxima? Is that possible with texput?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here, which are both completely not obvious; sorry about that. (1) Need to say `nounify(log)` and not just `log` in the call to `texput`. This is because `log(3)` is a so-called noun expression (as opposed to a verb expression). (2) Need to say `prefix` in the call to `texput` since `log` is typeset as a prefix operator in TeX.

```
(%i1) texput (nounify(log), "\\ln", prefix);
(%o1)                                 \ln
(%i2) tex(log(3));
$$\ln3$$
(%o2)                                false
```

Oh, looks like we need a trailing space to separate the `\ln` from the 3.

```
(%i3) texput (nounify(log), "\\ln ", prefix);
(%o3)                                \ln 
(%i4) tex(log(3));
$$\ln 3$$
(%o4)                                false
```

That seems to work as expected.